# I want to print aspx page datewise?

Tags: asp.net

I created a invoice format in ***aspx*** page
i want that when i click on print button it asks for

1. from and to date

   Blockquote and print from date to to date invoices, is it possible?

Comment: Please add the code you tried

Comment: which control u using to bind the datas (like grid view or some other?)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from the print dialog. You can add two form fields where the user can enter the from and to date and process this information serverside, returning only the results between those dates.

Comment: Sir if I convert my aspx page into pdf after that is it possible multiple print date wise????

Comment: What is "multiple print date wise"? Like I said, no, you have no influence on what gets printed after the user clicks Print from the browser, you will have to let the user make a date selection before that.

Comment: sir if i select from 03/01/2014 to 03/25/2014 invoice between these dates should be print one by one automatically is it possible?